# javadoc generated with gralde to include jax-rs @DefaultValue

Tags: gradle, jax-rs, javadoc

I have a project using jax-rs, I would like to generate javadoc in such a way that the annotation @DefaultValue would be documented

how can I achieve that with gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like

```
javadoc {
    options {
        links = ['https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/']
    }
}
```

@see [StandardJavadocDocletOptions.getLinks()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/StandardJavadocDocletOptions.html#getLinks())

@see [`javadoc -link extdocURL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDEDJFI)

Comment: How would that help? He wants that `@DefaultValue` is shown in the JavaDoc pages, not that its usage as parameter and so on is linked.

Comment: This would mean any `@DefaultValue` references in his javadocs would link through to the [DefaultValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) javadocs. Not sure what else he would be asking for?

Comment: That anything that is annotated with that annotation is documented as being annotated with this annotation.